# google script .getAs("application/pdf") randomly generates completely bold pdfs

Tags: pdf, google-docs

My script generates google docs based on three different google docs templates with data coming from a spreadsheet. The generated docs are converterd to pdf with 
    .getAs("application/pdf")
All works fine, except for the fact that randomly the conversion from document to pdf generates a pdf with all the text set to **bold**. The google doc is as it should be.

This happens completely at random. It happens with docs generated from all three the templates

Has anybody an idea what causes this or has someone the same experiences?

Kind regards,

Lorenz